# Why is my Sub triggering other functions that haven't been called?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code that loops through a range of cells, and for each coloured cell in that range, copies and pastes a column on two templates and copies the contents of the current cell into the new columns. 
My main problem here is that the loop reaches a certain point, and then somehow triggers other UDFs in the document which is making the code run fairly slow.

For the very first coloured cell the loop finds, it skips the second If statement (If ConstructFirst=True), triggers the next one, but after copying the taskName to the targeted column it jumps to a UDF which is trying to sum the values inside colored cells for a particular range before jumping to a second UDF which is summing a cell over a few different sheets.

Here is my code:

```
taskCount = 0
ConstructFirst = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cost Summary")
Set labourTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Labour Template")
Set plantTemplate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plant Template")

Set TaskList = ws.Range("TaskList[Work Activities]")
newLabCol = 19
newPlantCol = 13

For Each task In TaskList

    If task.Interior.ColorIndex > 0 And labourTemplate.Cells(9, newLabCol) <> task.Text Then
        taskName = task.Text
        taskID = ws.Cells(task.Row, 2)
        newLabCol = newLabCol + taskCount
        newPlantCol = newPlantCol + taskCount

        If ConstructFirst = True Then
            If labourTemplate.Cells(9, newLabCol) <> taskName Then
                labourTemplate.Range("S1:S74").Copy labourTemplate.Cells(1, newLabCol)
                labourTemplate.Cells(9, newLabCol) = taskName
                labourTemplate.Cells(8, newLabCol) = taskID
            End If
            If plantTemplate.Cells(8, newLabCol) <> taskName Then
                plantTemplate.Range("M1:M73").Copy plantTemplate.Cells(1, newPlantCol)
                plantTemplate.Cells(8, newPlantCol) = taskName
                plantTemplate.Cells(5, newPlantCol) = taskID
            End If
        taskCount = taskCount + 1
        End If

        If ConstructFirst = False And labourTemplate.Cells(9, 19) <> taskName And plantTemplate.Cells(8, 13) <> taskName Then

            labourTemplate.Cells(9, newLabCol) = taskName 'CODE TRIGGERS OTHER FUNCTIONS AFTER THIS LINE
            labourTemplate.Cells(8, newLabCol) = taskID

            plantTemplate.Cells(8, newPlantCol) = taskName
            plantTemplate.Cells(5, newPlantCol) = taskID
            ConstructFirst = True
            taskCount = taskCount + 1
        End If
    End If
Next task
```

And here is the first UDF that is triggered. Please note that this UDF is not my own work.

```
Function SumCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range)
Dim indRefColor As Long
Dim cellCurrent As Range
Dim sumRes
Dim rowCheck As String
Dim colCheck As String


Application.Volatile
sumRes = 0
indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
For Each cellCurrent In rData
    If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
        sumRes = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cellCurrent, sumRes)
    End If
Next cellCurrent

SumCellsByColor = sumRes
```

I had this function in a cell which referred to the same range that my loop was trying to look through, so I removed the function from that cell but it hasn't made a difference. I already feel like i'm pushing it with the amount of code displayed in this post so if anyone needs to see the second UDF triggered please comment and I will put it up. I am still fairly inexperienced with any type of coding so I realise that I might not be correctly grabbing any errors that might arise, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Application.Volatile means that the UDF will run every time a calculation event occurs, even if the range being calculated isn't part of the UDF's inputs.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-volatile-method-excel

Comment: I removed Application.Volatile from the UDF and stepped through it again but I still found the same issue

Comment: Put a break in the UDF code and check the input ranges to see if they're in the range you're working in.  If you don't need calculation at all during your run you can turn it off using `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`.  Don't forget to reset it when done.

Comment: It didn't look like the UDF was trying to use the same range I was working in, but I added that line to the beginning and then `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end and it works perfectly. Thank you! If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a break in the UDF code and check the input ranges to see if they're in the range you're working in.

If you don't need calculation at all during your run you can turn it off using

```
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual.
```

Don't forget to reset it when done.